# Return Don't turn like print

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, math, error-handling

I have a problem in a codewars kata
https://www.codewars.com/kata/58cbfe2516341cce1e000001/train/python

```
def count_zeros_n_double_fact(n): 
    res = []
    oddeven = []
    revers = []
    result = 1
    c = 0
    for i in range(n+1):
        if i % 2 == 0 and i != 0:
            oddeven.append(i)
    for x in oddeven:
        result = result * x
    for z in reversed(str(result)):
        if z == '0':
            c+=1
        else:
            break
    return c
```

I passed the tests but in the attempts any big number it return it zero

the tests with return:
[image: the tests with return]

the attempts with return:
[image: the attempts with return]

But, When I used print all answers has been correct

```
def count_zeros_n_double_fact(n): 
    res = []
    oddeven = []
    revers = []
    result = 1
    c = 0
    for i in range(n+1):
        if i % 2 == 0 and i != 0:
            oddeven.append(i)
    for x in oddeven:
        result = result * x
    for z in reversed(str(result)):
        if z == '0':
            c+=1
        else:
            break
    print (c)
```

attempts with print

[image: attempts with print]
Please Help ME!

Comment: Hint: look at the test cases that are failed. Are the input numbers odd or even? Now, think carefully about your logic. If the input number is `9`, what numbers will get multiplied together by your code? (Did you check? Can you think of a way to check? What if you try displaying `oddeven` before doing the multiplication?) What numbers *should* get multiplied together? Do you see why this causes a problem?

Comment: For future questions, [please try](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) to [find the problem yourself first](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). We do not give full answers for questions like this, because they do not meet the site standards; we require *specific* questions that can help someone else. To create a good question, first look for a problem by carefully studying what the code does, step by step; when you find a problem, create a proper [mre] for **only** the part that is a problem - and then see if there is still a meaningful question.

Comment: "But, When I used print all answers has been correct" - this is not the case. You have not properly understood the tester's feedback. The numbers that you get displayed from `print` are the same as the ones that are returned by `return` - but you must `return` in order to satisfy the tester. The tester cannot read what is displayed to the screen when it calls your function. It must use the return value.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel He does `return c` in the first version, which I believe is the one he's submitting to the tester. The second version is just to see what it's returning.

Comment: @Barmar ... yes, I understand that. The question says "When I used print all answers has been correct", but that clearly isn't true. It prints the answers that would have been returned otherwise, and those answers clearly are wrong half the time. (The tester fails everything when using print, but that's a separate problem.)

Comment: @KarlKnechtel You're right, I hadn't looked at that screenshot.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Thank you for your comment, i really tried to know the problem but I couldn't, thanks for your time and i will try to be more accurate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

##### Problem

Your logic is wrong, you're always using the odd numbers, but it's said

- if `n` is odd, multiply the odd numbers until `n`
- if `n` is even, multiply the even numbers until `n`

##### Fix

Take the required values as the exercice states

```
def count_zeros_n_double_fact(n): 
    res = []
    oddeven = []
    revers = []
    result = 1
    c = 0
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        if (i % 2 == 0 and n % 2 == 0)  or (i % 2 == 1 and n % 2 == 1):
            oddeven.append(i)
    for x in oddeven:
        result = result * x
    for z in reversed(str(result)):
        if z == '0':
            c+=1
        else:
            break
    return c
```

##### Improve

Loop only on every two values and multiply them directly, don't store them in a list

```
def count_zeros_n_double_fact(n):
    result = 1
    c = 0
    for i in range((n + 1) % 2 + 1, n + 1, 2):
        result *= i
    for z in reversed(str(result)):
        if z == '0':
            c += 1
        else:
            break
    return c
```

---

Other way

```
from functools import reduce
from operator import mul

def count_zeros_n_double_fact(n):
    result = str(reduce(mul, range((n + 1) % 2 + 1, n + 1, 2)))
    return len(result) - len(result.rstrip("0"))
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your great answer I appreciate your effort